# C sscanf exact length

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having a problem using the exact string length, %Ns, format modifier in sscanf. When buff contains `O 5 hello R 700` the code works fine. but when I try to have a space in the name field it doesn't work. ie, when buff contains `O 6 h ello R 700` it fails. it makes `name` contain "h" and flags contain "ello" instead of `name` containing "h ello"

```
// buff will contain something in the format of "O <name_length> <name> <flags> <mode>"

int namelen;
char name[BUFFSIZE];
char flags[BUFFSIZE];
char mode[20];

sscanf(buff, "O %d", &namelen);

char extractor[BUFFSIZE];
sprintf(extractor, "O %%d %%%ds %%s %%s", namelen);

sscanf(buff, extractor, &namelen, name, flags, mode);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%s` matches only non-whitespace.  You want `%[…]`, or better yet, `%c` (take care to add the trailing NUL yourself, though).

Also, `%*d` will scan a digit but *not* save it, which I think you would prefer (since you've already got `namelen` from before).

But overall I would probably avoid generating the format string at runtime.

```
int namelen, offset;
char name[BUFFSIZE];
char flags[BUFFSIZE];
char mode[20];

sscanf(buff, "O %d %n", &namelen, &offset);
memcpy(name, buff + offset, namelen);
name[namelen + 1] = '\0';
sscanf(buff + offset + namelen, " %s %s", flags, mode);
```

(Untested, but something like that should work.)

Comment: nice. all I had to change was `name[namelen + 1]` to just `name[namelen]` and it worked perfect. and you taught me %*d and %n. many thanks.